# Directed Graph from OverStreetMap API

Tags: javascript, api, openstreetmap, directed-graph

I am searching for a solution of how to get a directed graph by maybe manipulating data from OverStreetMap using javascript, but I haven't been able to find a way to do so yet. Is it even possible? Is there maybe a library that does this?

Comment: Do you mean a graph representing the osm ways and nodes? I don't know of a library just looking for clarification

Comment: A directed graph build of edges and vertices, where edges that are connected are representing a road/way, i hope this clears it up

Comment: What about [graph-from-osm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/graph-from-osm)?

Comment: Yesss thank you, I've just came upon this library and I hope this works for me. If it does I'll answer my own question I guess.